# one field(Member id) or mulitple fields(first name, last name) should be made mandatory using jquery validator plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins, field

```
$("#memberSearchForm").validate({
            rules: {                
                memberId: {
                      require_from_group: [1, ".memberDetails"],
                      number:"true"
                    },
                    firstname: {

                      require_from_group: [1, ".memberDetails"]
                    },
                    lastname:{

                        require_from_group: [1, ".memberDetails"]
                    },
                    memDob:{

                        require_from_group: [1, ".memberDetails"]
                    }

            }
```

I want either member id should be mandatory or all ( firstname, lastname, memDob) to be mandatory. Can someone help me on this ?